# Laravel 5 how to display blade content on guest/authenticated user?

Tags: laravel, authentication, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

I can read from the documentation that I can write the following in order to understand if the user is authenticated :

```
if (Auth::check())
{
 // The user is logged in...
}
```

Until there everything is working for me (authentication)

What I still miss is how should I manage the authentication with blade.
In order, for example to display a different menu, if the user Is or isn't authenticated.

But I wouldn't duplicate all my blade templates to obtain the above.
I would like to understand how to place conditions(where controller or view?) in order to display (yeld) different content based on current auth status

e.g. the pseudo code I have in mind for my app.blade.php file:

```
....
<body >
     @if (Auth::check())
     {
     @include('menu')
     @yield('content')
     }@else{
     @include('menu.guest')
     }
</body>
```

is this the good way?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Its correct. Except you should avoid the curly parenthesis "{ }" for if and else.

Comment: I found out that also naming blade files with dot notation gives me problem/errors: menu.guest ---> menuGuest

Comment: When you mention "menu.guest" you are actually referring to a blade file named "guest.blade.php" in a folder named menu within your views folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can check it like that, but you have few errors in your code, you cant use curly brackets in blade template. Do something like this.

```
<body >
     @if (Auth::check())
         @include('menu')
         @yield('content')
     @else
         @include('menu.guest')
     @endif
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use blade directives take a [look](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#control-structures)

```
    @auth
       // The user is authenticated...
   @endauth
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this way is good when you are using same template.
You can also make separate file and include as per your authentication status.